# create a link to show view's images in Colorbox when the images link to their content

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-views, colorbox

I have a view that displays an image field (among other fields) from some content nodes.  I want the image field to link to the content node so I've set its formatter to Image and linked it to the node.  However, I'd like to have an additional link on the view page (possibly in the view header area) that would display all the images on the page in a colorbox.

I've tried adding a “rel” tag to all the images displayed by the view and then configuring the link in the header area to have a class of “colorbox” and a rel tag that matches those of the images and a src attribute set to the URL of the image from the view's first row but all I get in the colorbox then is that single image, not the rest of the ones on the page.

I'm a bit naïve in my understanding of how this all works and would appreciate any advice on how to get this working.

Comment: Share the code that you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this by making two views. The main list view as you described and then a second view with a block display that just lists the images with a colorbox style plugin.

This assumes you don't need the two views tied together just the same content. Both views can pull the same arguments so it should keep them fully synced.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me come up with a solution that sort of works.  I didn't create a second view, I just added another copy of the image field to the original view and set its formatter to Colorbox and gave it a class that I could use to hide it in my css (display: none).  I then added a link in the view header area that had a class of colorbox, a rel tag matching those from the second copy of the image field and a src attribute set to the URL of the image from the first row.  I actually had to add a third copy of the image field to make that work.  (continued below)

Comment: I set the formatter of the third copy to Image URL (using the Imager URL Formatter module).  That formatter gives you the URL of the image as the name implies.  Now the only problem I have is I get two copies of the first rows image in the colorbox, one from the link and one from the first row itself.  But I might be able to live with that.  This all seems pretty hacky and I'd appreciate any tips on cleaning it up!